# JavaEE PaaS for cloud applications

Tags: jakarta-ee

Are there any JavaEE platform for developing cloud based application? I am looking for something similar to what Microsoft Azure platform provides.  And importantly I need a full stack implementation including EJB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want full stack of J2EE I would highly recommend going with Amazon EC2, just select one of the many available AMI's best suited for your needs, and you are ready to go and scale.
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

Comment: But how easy is the configuration part. Does it require a lot of management. Knowledge of any new technologies other than java is required to develop in Amazon? How good is the support for these AMIs?